# adding extension MySql (PHP/JavaBridge)

Tags: php, mysql, php-java-bridge

I have installed java bridge in my server tomcat 6.0 successful.
But when I add another application,in the same folder, that uses a MySQL database, Tomcat  generates the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\Aphe Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\e\php_mysql.dll' - Le module specific est introuvable.
in Unknown on line 0
```

knowing that :

1. I copy the correct VERSION of the PHP extension "php_mysql.dll" to the correspond "ext" directory, in my case it's in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\dhtmlx\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\ext"
2. add this line,"extension = php_mysql.dll" in php.ini and mysql.ini file.

Comment: You say that you've copied `php_mysql.dll` to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\dhtmlx\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\ext`, but Tomcat sais it's looking for it in `C:\Program Files\Aphe Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\cgi\x86-windows\e`.

Comment: I rename the file:webapps/JavaBridge directory to file:webapps/dhtmlx

Answer (score 0):

Did you add mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar?